# React-navigation - goBack behaviour in nested navigators (stack inside drawer)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using a `stack` navigator inside `drawer` navigator - recently upgraded from v4. Trying to implement custom back button on headerLeft. `goBack` function on the stack screen is going back on the drawer navigator instead of the `stack`. I don't know if I'm missing something or if it's a bug on v5. The `goBack` should go to the previous screen in the `stack` not the `drawer`. See the gif below; using the gesture goes back on the `stack` and the default back button on the header goes back onto the `stack` too. It's only my custom back button with the problem.

[image]

```
export function BlogsStack({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={'Blogs'}
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: true,
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
        cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
        headerStyle: {
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
        },
        headerTintColor: themeVars.headerTintColor,
        headerBackground: () => {
          return <HeaderBackground />;
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Blogs"
        component={Blogs}
        options={{
          title: 'Blogs',
          headerTitle: () => (
            <View>
              <HeaderButton title={'Blogs'} />
            </View>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
              style={drawerStyles.menuIconContainer}>
              <FeatherIcon
                style={drawerStyles.menuIcon}
                name="menu"
                size={themeVars.hamburgerIconSize}
                color={themeVars.hamburgerIconColor}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => <View />,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BlogSingle"
        component={BlogSingle}
        options={{
          headerTitle: () => (
            <View>
              <HeaderButton title={'Blog'} />
            </View>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
              style={drawerStyles.menuIconContainer}>
              <FeatherIcon
                style={drawerStyles.menuIcon}
                name="chevron-left"
                size={themeVars.hamburgerIconSize}
                color={themeVars.hamburgerIconColor}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => <View />,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


export class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <AppDrawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName={'Home'}
          drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
          drawerContentOptions={{
            labelStyle: {
              fontFamily: themeVars.boldFont,
              color: themeVars.primaryColor,
            },
            activeTintColor: 'black',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'black',
            inactiveTintColor: 'white',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
            itemStyle: {
              marginVertical: 0,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: 'red',
              margin: 0,
              padding: 0,
            },
          }}>
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeStack}
            initialRouteName={'Home'}
            options={{
              drawerLabel: 'Home ',
              drawerIcon: () => (
                <FeatherIcon
                  color={themeVars.primaryColor}
                  name="home"
                  size={themeVars.drawerIconSize}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            initialRouteName="Blogs"
            backBehavior="order"
            name="Blogs"
            component={BlogsStack}
            options={{
              drawerLabel: 'Blogs ',
              drawerIcon: () => (
                <FontAwesome5
                  color={themeVars.primaryColor}
                  name="wordpress"
                  size={themeVars.drawerIconSize}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </AppDrawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? Having the same problem.

Comment: @ovabrandon I did indeed... Follow this issue on git: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted out my issue by following the docs. The issue was that I was passing the wrong `navigation`.

> You need to use the correct navigation prop in your header, i.e. by
> defining a callback for the options:
> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options#options-prop-on-screen
>
> You're using navigation prop passed from the parent navigator which is
> a drawer, so the action is performed in the drawer.

Follow the git issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8806

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear : we have to get the navigation prop from specific screen itself hence the screen stack will be notified of the history. using hook doesn't do this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).